# set shortcut depending on filetype

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

For some markup and programming languages I use VIM and the usual procedure for me checking if my code works is `:w` and `!<compile>`. Depending on the filetype `<compile>` can be very different programs, for example `pdflatex %` for .tex files, `cargo run` for rust code or simply a general `make`.

Is it possible to define a shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) for VIM to safe the currently open file and compile the project dependent on the filetype opened?

Comment: `:help make`, `:help ftplugin`, `:help :compiler`

Comment: and `:help makeprg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben and Christian pointed to the important parts of help.

To give you a example, try this. I just tested it with a simple TeX file:

```
let tex_flavor = 'pdflatex'
autocmd FileType tex  compiler tex

set autowrite
map ,c :make %<CR>
```

This sets the compiler for TeX. See `:help compiler-tex`, there are a few options to set. I just chose `tex_flavor`, so pdflatex is run.

After loading a tex file, just hit `,c` and the file will be saved (because of `autowrite`) and `:make` is called. This will run pdflatex. For me it just created a dvi file.

If you want a different call to `:make` for tex files add something like this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType tex map <buffer> ,c :make -draftmode % <CR>
```

Then `,c` is mapped different in a text file.

For Rust: There is a `:compiler cargo`, but unfortunately no help file.